# org/apache/log4j/Priority Error in Test Case

Tags: java, ant, log4j, testng, testng-eclipse

I have created some test cases in my project using test-ng. When I am running the test cases from eclipse, it's working fine. but from my ant build script, TestNG gives following error:

```
run.unit.tests:
   [testng] [TestNG] [Error]
   [testng] An error occurred while instantiating class com.sydac.tangara.tos.backend.test.FaultFunctionalityTests: org/apache/log4j/Priority
```

Anybody knows about this error??
Reply if more information required.

Comment: It looks like `log4j` is missing in the classpath provided by ant. Could you share your ant build.xml file?